# TypeError: get_orders() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' - Connect to database and transform it to panda dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I ran this class object and i get this error: "TypeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object is not callable". I've purposely did not add server and database name.

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd 

#create connection to our database
class db: 
     DRIVER = 'DRIVER={SQL SERVER};'
     SERVER = 'SERVER=TestServer;'
     DATABASE = 'DATABASE=TestBox;'
     TRUST = 'Trust_Connection=yes;'

def __init__(self): 
    self.connection =pyodbc.connect(self.DRIVER+self.SERVER+self.DATABASE+self.TRUST)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    self.cursor = self.cursor.tables()
    rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    
def execute(self, query): 
    self.execute = self.cursor.execute(query)
    return self.execute

class orders(db): 
     def get_orders(self): 
     query = "SELECT Ship_CustomerID, Ship_CustomerName, Contract, CONVERT(Date,Date_Order,101) as 'Date' FROM [Datamart].[GSC].[Fact_Orders] WHERE Contract LIKE 'MED%' and Date_Order BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and GETDATE() ORDER by Date_Order DESC "
    self.__orders = pd.read_sql(self.query,self.cursor)
    return self.__orders
    

   database = db() 
   database 
   orders = orders 
   orders.get_orders()
```

Comment: Unrelated to the python, but a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is going to return 10 arbitrary rows; they could easily be 10 different ones every time you run said query.

Comment: I'm just testing to make sure it's able to connect to the database

Comment: Have you checked that `self.connection` is not `None`? It could be `None` because `Trust_Connection=yes;` should probably be `Trusted_Connection=yes;` and could be causing in an invalid connection string type of error.

Answer (score 0):

created a new class object to pull database to dataFrame.

```
enter code here
class orders(db): 
def get_order(self): 
    query = "SELECT TOP (1000)* FROM [Datamart].[GSC].[Fact_Orders]"
    pd.set_option('display.max.columns', 100)
    df = pd.read_sql(query, self.connection)
    return df
```